# Signature does not match using Signed Url with GCS

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I intend to let the users of my application upload files directly to GCS, for which I am using a [PUT request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload) with a signed url. My code in python looks like this:

```py
def get(self):
    base_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/' + self.get_bucket_name()
    expiration = utils.unix_time_secs(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1))

    string_to_sign = (  'PUT' + "\n" +
                        '' + "\n" +
                        '' + "\n" +
                        str(expiration) + "\n" +
                        '' + "\n" +
                        'my-bucket.appspot.com')

    signed_string = app_identity.sign_blob(string_to_sign)[1]
    signature = base64.b64encode(signed_string)
    signature = urllib.quote(signature, safe='')
    google_access_id = app_identity.get_service_account_name()

    params = '?GoogleAccessId={0}&Expires={1}&Signature={2}'.format(
                        google_access_id, expiration, signature)


    self.template_values['base_url'] = base_url
    self.template_values['params'] = params
    self.render('testA.html')
```

On the client side, I use an XMLHttpRequest to send the file to GCS:

```js
function gCloud (base_url, params, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = document.querySelector('#fotos').files[0]

    //Here goes an event listener (callback)

    url = base_url + '/' + file.name + params
    xhr.open("PUT", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type)
    xhr.send(file)
}
```

The problem is that when I send this request I get a 403 Forbidden Error that says that the calculated signature did not match the one I provided. It is probably a dumb error, but I can't get this to work. What could be the problem?

EDIT:

I tried using google-cloud-python, and tried this code (which worked):

```py
def get(self):
    bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket(self.get_bucket_name())
    blob = bucket.blob('Yosemite.jpg')

    expiration = utils.unix_time_secs(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1))
    base_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration, "PUT", 'image/jpeg')
    self.template_values['base_url'] = base_url
    self.render('testA.html')
```

The problem now is that since 'generate_signed_url' is a method of the Blob class it already assumes I know the unique path of the object to create the url, like in blob = bucket.blob('Yosemite.jpg'), which I don't. What if the user wants to upload Space.jpg? Instead of creating my-bucket/Space.jpg, Yosemite.jpg it will be overwritten, so I will have Yosemite.jpg and if I open the image it will actually be Space.jpg. How can I solve this?

Plus, if I don't include Content-Type='image-jpeg' in the 'generate_signed_url' function, the signature will not match. What if the user uploads a png instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL-signing code is tricky and notoriously hard to debug. Fortunately, Google's google-cloud library has a "generate_signed_url" function that takes care of this for you. I highly encourage you to use it instead of rewriting it yourself. [Here's the documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage-blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url).

Even if you don't want to use it, you may want to check out the [implementation of the signing logic in Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/_modules/google/cloud/credentials.html).

Now, if you want to debug it yourself, checking the error message is super useful. It will include a complete copy of the string the server checked the signature of. Print your "string_to_sign" and see if it matches the value that comes back from the server. If it doesn't, that's your problem. If it does, move on to the actual signing.

Looking over your code, my guess is that the problem may be that you are not URL-escaping your google_access_id, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried escaping the google_access_id, but that didn't solve it. I tried using the google-cloud-python library and edited the question accordingly, but from what I understand that function assumes I know things like the name of the file or it's content type before passing the url to the user. What can I do about this?

Comment: OH. You're trying to edit the URL on the client side to append an object name? That won't work. The whole point of signed URLs is to prevent clients from editing the request. If you want the user to be able to specify the object name, there's another option for that: signed POST request policy documents. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

Comment: I'll use POST for this case, I'll keep PUT for the other ones. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the objectname part of the canonical resource.  This is required, it is not possible to create a PUT signed URL that allows the user to choose a filename, you must specify it when you sign the URL.

Also note that the body of the response for a SignatureDoesNotMatch error should include some XML with the stringToSign -- aka the string the server expected you to sign.  You can compare this to the string you actually signed to determine where the mismatch is coming from.

Comment: You are right, that was part of the problem. The other thing was the Content-Type, I had to specify it to make it work, even though it's supposed to be optional. Anyway, I'm using the client library now, which takes care of it. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: content-type is optional, but the PUT request must match the signature.  If you do not specify content-type in the signature the PUT request must also not contain the content-type.